# Conditional date period formula needed for summing

Tags: excel, date

I am looking for a formula that will calculate the time I spent during a billing period.

In column A, I have dates and in column, F I have the total time spent. My billing period runs from the 21st of one month to the 20th of the next month. I would like a formula that looks in column A for dates of each billing period and groups them together and then calculates total time spent during that billing period. Can Excel do this?

Here is a sample spreadsheet

```
1. Col A                Col F
2. 12/5/2015             1.0
3. 13/5/2015             0.5
4. 16/5/2015             0.7
5. 21/5/2015             3.2
6. 29/5/2015             0.9
```

There are two billing periods above: May (21 Apr to 20 May) and June (21 May to 20 June). I would like a formula that calculates total time for May (2.2 hrs) and June (4.1 hrs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something using the [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5) together with [EDATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edate-function-1586b161-4361-4a6d-939b-9d96eae962a8) and [DATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATE-function-B91BEF00-4B5B-4EE0-B80E-06E68B1DFF29) like this,

```
=sumifs(f:f, a:a, ">="&date(2015, 4, 21), a:a, "<"&edate(date(2015, 4, 21), 1))
=sumifs(f:f, a:a, ">="&date(2015, 5, 21), a:a, "<"&edate(date(2015, 5, 21), 1))
```

With no mention as to how you are storing the dates governing the time periods, I've simply hard-coded the start dates in and used EDATE to add a month.

Comment: Hi Jeeped. This works with a slight amendment - not using EDATE. With EDATE it was calculating the total F column.

Comment: Hi again Jeeped. My bad. Your formula works. When I originally used it I erroneously changed the second criteria to read 2015,5,21 rather than keeping 2015,4,21 and adding 1 to increment the month with edate. Sorry about that. So EDATE as you've stated works.

Comment: @TerryAlly - Thanks for clearing that up. While hardcoding the end of the time period in will work as well, I wanted to demonstrate the ease of  *add-a-month* with EDATE. Glad you got sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMIFS(F7:F11,A7:A11,"<"& E8,A7:A11,">"&E9)
```

Where E8 and E9 are cells with biling periods date

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to add a column which works out the accounting period as a number:-

```
=MONTH(A2)-MONTH($H$2)+(DAY(A2)>=DAY($H$2))
```

where column A contains the dates and H2 contains the base date (21/4/15).

Then you could use it in a pivot table to get the sum of the times for each accounting period.

[image]